# ASP.Net Treeview control and tag property for each node

Tags: asp.net

if tree node does not have tag property like windows treeview control then i just want to know how could i attach the tag property with each tree node. is it possible if yes then please help me with code sample.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the information that you want to persist can be represented as a string then you can use the [Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treenode.value.aspx) property of the `TreeNode` object:

> Gets or sets a non-displayed value
>   used to store any additional data
>   about the node, such as data used for
>   handling postback events.